# Can I Store files locally with filepicker?

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I want to store files in my local storage.

Is it possible with file-picker? I've read the documents but couldn't figure out the possibility

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my own question,
I contacted the dev team of file-picker and found out that
there is no such option